# Javassist: How to access new created local variable

Tags: bytecode, instrumentation, javassist

Say I create a local variable at the method entry.

`method.insertBefore("final String id=UUID.randomUUID().toString();");`

How do I access it at the exit point?

`method.insertAfter("read(id);");`

---

In Javassist tutorial

> Accessing local variables declared in the method is not allowed

http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial2.html

Comment: What is the problem with `method.insertAfter("read(id);");`?

Comment: @Holger It reads id as a filed. Bytecode doesn't keep variable name

Comment: So you hit a limitation of Javassist. Generally, I think doing bytecode instrumentation on a source code level will always hit limitations for any nontrivial task. There’s no way around learning, how the bytecode works, and use the bytecode level API.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```java
method.addLocalVariable("id",pool.get("java.lang.String"));
method.insertBefore("id=UUID.randomUUID().toString();");
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they miss an opportunity to educate and empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Please always include a plain English explanation of why/how your suggestion works and why you feel it is a good idea for the OP.